# Update Google Play Store on Android Emulator (Exception:Google Play Services not available due to error 2)

Tags: android, android-emulator, google-play-services

**Update Google Play Store on Android Emulator** (Exception:Google Play Services not available due to error 2)

I have problem of Ad-mob video in my Galaxy-Nexus device. 
and i don't have the Device.So thats why i wants to update my Android Emulator for testing the Application.
(i am sorry for grammar mistakes)  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by adding permission to manifest file com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES.

or the other way is to update your google services library.
I would suggest locating these files and then manually installing them via the adb like so:

adb -install "C:.........\com.android.vending-4452000.apk

adb -install "C:.........\com.google.android.gms-4452000.apk
or the greater version of services